# MongoDb Upsert Deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, deadlock, upsert

Is it possible to reach deadlocks on MongoDb upsert operations?
I'm performing a load-test on an upsert operation that looks like:

```
db.update(
    { foo: {a: 'xxx', b: 'yyy'}, $lt: {"order.date": someDate}}, 
    {order: order}, 
    true, false);
```

Deployed on Azure machine with the official mongodb C# driver. Single instance, no replica-sets or sharding yet.

When I run 5000 of this same update command, split among 200 concurrent threads (2 machines @ 100 threads each), most of the times it will end with deadlocks. I.e. many of the calls never come back. I can see from db.currentOp() via the console, many of the updates are still there, stuck in a locked:true, with lockType:'write'.

Why does this deadlock happen? How is it possible? And how do I prevent it?  Is there any specific guidelines of what kind of operations should be avoided to avoid deadlocks on mongodb?

Is $atomic related to the solution? I don't even know how to set $atomic:true on c#, though it's probably irrelevant to this deadlock issue.

Comment: Upsert is an update operation?

Comment: it's an update with the upsert flag set to true

Answer (score 0):

[$atomic should help](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-Blocking)

```
db.update(
    {
        $and: [
            { foo: { a: 'xxx', b: 'yyy' },
            { $lt: { 'order.date': someDate } }
        ],
        $atomic: true
    },
    { order: order },
    true,
    false
);
```

also, you may want an $and clause.  check your explain for your call to see what indexes are being used, etc...